# Same code format with intelliji than with maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, code-formatting, checkstyle

Currently in my project, we format the code by using intelliji. Is there a way to configure maven checkstyle so it check the same rules than intelliji use?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/06/highlighting-checkstyle-links-using-maven-and-intellij-idea.html

Comment: I want to know the same thing. Can I make checkstyle validate that the code rules defined in the IntelliJ formatter? The link by @ElHoss above shows how to make IntelliJ aware of checkstyle, which can be done with a plugin anyway.